# Resolving error-prone ConstructorLeaksThis warning on constructors which call other constructors

Tags: java, constructor, errorprone

We have a few classes with the usual pattern for sharing constructor logic:

```
public X(E... processors)
{
    this(ImmutableList.copyOf(processors));
}

public X(Collection<E> processors)
{
    this.processors = ImmutableList.copyOf(processors);
}
```

In this situation, error-prone complains with `ConstructorLeaksThis`

```
.../X.java:61: error: [ConstructorLeaksThis] Constructors should not pass the 'this' reference out in method invocations, since the object may not be fully constructed.
        this(ImmutableList.copyOf(processors));
        ^
    (see http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ConstructorLeaksThis)
```

If this implementation pattern is actually unsafe, I'm sure it can be refactored out to static methods fairly easily, but I guess the question is, *is* is unsafe? Maybe this isn't what the compiler check intended to detect?

Comment: The only problem I see is that you are unnecessary creating two instances of `ImmutableList`.

Comment: @tsolakp copyOf returns the same instance if it's already an `ImmutableList`, but this was really just one example anyway, you could also have a constructor which calls an overload with one more parameter and you get the same warning there.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the javadoc mentioning it.

Comment: @tsolakp I believe it falls under the bit where it says "Despite the method name, this method attempts to avoid actually copying the data when it is safe to do so. The exact circumstances under which a copy will or will not be performed are undocumented and subject to change." The implementation detail in the version I'm looking at right now is that if the ImmutableList was returned as a partial view of another list, it does the copy anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Error-prone](http://errorprone.info/) defines [ConstructorLeaksThis](http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/ConstructorLeaksThis) problem:

> During the execution of a constructor, it’s dangerous to make the new
>   instance accessible to other code. Fields of the instance, including
>   final fields, may not yet be initialized, and executing instance
>   methods may yield unexpected results.

...And from your code, you're not violating the rule, also Java documentation wrote about [Using this with a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html), it's a false positive, the same issue was reported [here](https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/655).

BTW, you can add `@SuppressWarnings("ConstructorLeaksThis")` in your constructor to suppress the errors or refactor your code without `@SuppressWarnings` to prevent hidden bugs.

Comment: I will probably file it with them directly and get it fixed for real. I dislike `@SuppressWarnings` on the whole because later, someone adds code which actually does violate the warning, and you never find out because it was suppressed. Almost every time I have found some real WTF bug which a warning would have picked up, someone had put a suppression in the area.

Comment: Yes, you may report a bug, I've added a link to a similar issue in my answer.

Comment: That seems like the exact same issue so I'm just gonna subscribe to it. I wonder why I couldn't find a ticket about it initially...

Comment: (Also, what if someone adds code which actually leaks `this` in the same constructor after I suppress the warning? This is why I was saying I don't like suppression...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's a bug.

Typically this error means that you passing a reference to the current unconstructed object, ie `someList.add(this)`.

However constructor chaining is perfectly fine and a often a good practice.